# Adding a new item in database through combobox

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, combobox

I am having a database and I use it through Entity Framework, I need to update the data by editing the other items in text boxes and grid, that is working fine and below is the code:
In aspx.cs

```
protected void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        obj.Address = AppAddress.Text;
        obj.City = AppCity.Text;
        obj.Email = AppEmail.Text;
        obj.Notes = AppComments.Text;
        obj.Postal = AppPostal.Text;
        obj.AppraiserAppraiserCompanyId = ApprCompCmbx.SelectedIndex;
        obj.ProvinceState = Province.SelectedIndex;
        apprblobj.GetUpdate(obj);
        Response.Write("<script>alert('You have successfully updated the Data');</script>");
}
```

call in the BL:

```
 public void GetUpdate(Appraiser appObj)
    {
        obj.UpdateData(appObj);

    }
```

and in the DAL

```
 public void UpdateData(Appraiser apprObj)
    {

        try
        {
            var Appsave = context.Appraisers.FirstOrDefault(App => App.AppraiserId == apprObj.AppraiserId);
            if (Appsave != null)
            {
                Appsave.AppraiserName = apprObj.AppraiserName;
                Appsave.AppraiserAppraiserCompanyId = apprObj.AppraiserAppraiserCompanyId;
                Appsave.Address = apprObj.Address;
                Appsave.City = apprObj.City;
                Appsave.ProvinceState = apprObj.ProvinceState;
                Appsave.Email = apprObj.Email;
                Appsave.Postal = apprObj.Postal;
                Appsave.Notes = apprObj.Notes;

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

             log.Debug("Appraiser : UpdateData: " + ex.Message + " Trace : " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Now I wanto to add a new item through the same combobox and on the button click functionality as it is doing all the work like add, update and delete.
Kindly provide me the hint: This I know that addobject(*_*_) will ve used in place of savechanges etc.

Comment: In stead of getting an `Appsave` object from the context, create a new one, add it to `context.Appraisers` and for the rest do the same.

Comment: I have done the same and its working now. Thanks!